# JavaScript async callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have some code that selects values from a WEB SQL database, which is done with the following code:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(query, params_array, result, error);
        });
```

In the callback function "result" I simply return the affected rows to the function that called db.transaction()

The call looks like this:

```
database.select(<some params, not imporntant for now>, function(result){
//do stuff
}
```

if I call it once I get exactly the output from the db that I expected, but when I do this call multiple times, only the callback function of the last call will be executed (I tried anonymous and named callback functions).

How can I make this asyncronous calls work without nesting the callbacks into each other like this:

```
database.select(<some params>, function(result){
    //do stuff
    //call again
    database.select(<some params>, function(result){
        //and so on...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name your functions but this is 10x less readable :D

```
database.select(<some params>, first);

function first(result) {
    //do stuff
    //call again
    database.select(<some params>, second);
}

function second() {
    //and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that I could nest them like this, but is there any option where I don´t have to nest it like this?

Comment: @puchmu for example promises

Comment: altough not the answer I was hoping for, still a good answer, so I will accept it. Thanks